# gethostbyname() processes resolving consistently even from different threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gethostbyname

I conducted an experiment with DNS resolving by gethostbyname() from different threads. I turned off network link and ran program below. And output was like this

```
gethostbyname started at 1411234734
gethostbyname started at 1411234734
gethostbyname started at 1411234734
gethostbyname finished at 1411234774
gethostbyname finished at 1411234814
gethostbyname finished at 1411234854
```

gethostbyname() started at the same time, but finished one by one with 40 sec timeout.

Then i experemented with getaddrinfo(). And it looks like this function doesn't suffer from this problem

```
getaddrinfo started at 1411235759
getaddrinfo started at 1411235759
getaddrinfo started at 1411235759
getaddrinfo finished at 1411235799
getaddrinfo finished at 1411235799
getaddrinfo finished at 1411235799
```

So, why I got this result and is this behavior specific for Linux only?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *resolve_ghbn(void *host) {
    printf("gethostbyname started at %d\n", time(NULL));
    struct hostent *rslv = gethostbyname((char*)host);
    printf("gethostbyname finished at %d\n", time(NULL));

    return NULL;
}

void *resolve_gai(void *host) {
    struct addrinfo *result;
    printf("getaddrinfo started at %d\n", time(NULL));
    int res = getaddrinfo(host, NULL, NULL, &result);
    printf("getaddrinfo finished at %d\n", time(NULL));
    if (res == 0)
        freeaddrinfo(result);

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *domains[] = {"google.com", "google.cy", "google.us"};
    pthread_t threads[3];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, resolve_ghbn, domains[i]);
    }

    void *retval;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], &retval);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either use `getaddrinfo()` or use a global mutex. What's the difference in behavior, I see 40 seconds timeout in both cases, plus how you turn off the network link and how you check that it's turned off?

Comment: Hey, I see it now. I'll prepare an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getaddrinfo()` function doesn't share any global/static variables and is thus reentrant an therefore thread-safe. It returns result in memory allocated using `malloc()` and the user is responsible for using `freeaddrinfo()` which in turn uses `free()` to allocate the data. Therefore you are allowed to run `getaddrinfo()` simultaneously from multiple threads and the the individual instances run in parallel.

On the other hand, `gethostbyname()` returns a pointer to global/static data and thus [is not reentrant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09). The user is not responsible for freeing the data. Therefore you *are not allowed* to run `gethostbyname()` simultaneously from multiple threads. According to your tests, the GNU C library apparently serializes the calls to avoid errors resulting from the parallel run.

You should generally avoid using `gethostbyname()` as it's somewhat obsoleted by `getaddrinfo()` but the latter is [not a perfect replacement](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14990), at least in glibc. I would recommend using `getaddrinfo()` and employ workarounds for its bugs where appropriate.

You could find out more by examining the source code.