# C :: Threads Inconsistently Open a Sending Socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, gethostbyname

I am building a C program and I’m wrestling with a weird – and inconsistent – thread and socket error with `gethostbyname()` that I’ve never seen before.

Some environmental stuff first:  I’m working on a Ubuntu box, and my code is compiled with GCC:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject# gcc -v
...
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
root@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject#
```

The objective here:  I’ve developed another C program which will someday be a network service, I hope.  The server is working fine, but I need to stress-test it.  So I’ve built a client program to bombard it with simulated network requests.  Once the server is up and listening on TCP 12345, the client program just needs to do the following:

- For N times, spin up a detached worker thread

  - Each thread should open a sending socket, then send some data to 127.0.0.1, via TCP 12345
  - After sending, a thread should immediately terminate

This should be child’s play.  I want to use large numbers of N to see what happens when my server is pounded.

Let me walk you through my code, then describe the problem.  The program is relatively simple.  There's a few structs and then `main()`.  Basically, `main()` loops for N = `numThreads`, creating a detached worker thread each time.  Each thread is given a populated `package` struct, with information it will use later:

```
typedef struct{
   int sock;
   struct sockaddr address;
   int addr_len;
} connection_t;

typedef struct{
   char* IP;
   int port, myNum;
} package;


void process(void* pack);                  // code for the thread, see below...


int main( int argc, char ** argv ){
   pthread_t  thread;
   int        numThreads = 10;             // or 100 or 1000 or whatever
   char       svrIP[20] = "127.0.0.1";
   int        portNumber = 12345;

   int i=0;
   for( ; i<numThreads; i++){

      package* pack   = (package*) malloc( sizeof(package) );
      pack->IP        = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char) * 20 );
      strcpy( pack->IP, svrIP );
      pack->port      = portNumber;
      pack->myNum     = i;

      pthread_create(&thread, NULL, process, (void*) pack);
      pthread_detach(thread);

      free( pack->IP );
      free( pack );
   }

   sleep(1);

   printf("END OF PROGRAM\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Everything above works great, regardless of what I set for `numThreads`.  Now for the thread’s code.  Upon birth, the thread tries to open a socket and then send a text string.  Then the thread terminates.  Note all that `fprintf()` code around `gethostbyname()` – I’ll be referring to it later:

```
void process(void* pack){
   int                  len, sock = -1;
   struct sockaddr_in   address;
   struct hostent *     host;

   char* msg = "Some text string here for the server...";

   printf("THREAD %d STARTED:  %s  --  %d\n", ((package*)pack)->myNum, ((package*)pack)->IP, ((package*)pack)->port );

   // create the socket
   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (sock <= 0){
      fprintf( stderr, "Thread %d: error: cannot create socket\n", ((package*)pack)->myNum );
      pthread_exit(0);
   }

   // connect to server
   address.sin_family = AF_INET;
   address.sin_port = htons( ((package*)pack)->port );
   host = gethostbyname( ((package*)pack)->IP );
   if (!host){
      fprintf( stderr, "Thread %d: error: unknown host %s  --  Error is:  (%d) \”%s\”\n",
            ((package*)pack)->myNum,
            ((package*)pack)->IP,
            errno, strerror(errno));
      pthread_exit(0);
   }

   memcpy(&address.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
   if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))){
      fprintf( stderr, "Thread %d: error: cannot connect to host %s\n", ((package*)pack)->myNum, ((package*)pack)->IP );
      pthread_exit(0);
   }

   printf("Thread %d: Sending message \”%s\”\n", ((package*)pack)->myNum, msg);

   len = strlen(msg);
   write(sock, &len, sizeof(int));
   write(sock, msg, len);

   printf("Thread %d: message sent, exiting...\n", ((package*)pack)->myNum );

   close(sock);

   pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Okay, so that’s the code.  So here’s the issue:

Regardless of what value I set for `numThreads`, some worker threads successfully open a socket, and some don’t.  The ones who fail are failing on that call to `gethostbyname()`.  Check out the below; I’ve set `numThreads` to 10, which means I should be seeing Threads 0 through 9 launch:

```
me@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject# ./runTest
THREAD 2 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
THREAD 5 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
THREAD 3 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
THREAD 3 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
THREAD 4 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
THREAD 7 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
Thread 7: Sending message "Some text string here for the server..."
Thread 7: message sent, exiting...
THREAD 7 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
Thread 7: Sending message "Some text string here for the server..."
Thread 7: message sent, exiting...
THREAD 8 STARTED:  127.0.0.1  --  24601
Thread 8: Sending message "Some text string here for the server..."
Thread 8: message sent, exiting...
THREAD 9 STARTED:    --  24601
THREAD 9 STARTED:    --  24601
Thread 9: Sending message "Some text string here for the server..."
Thread 9: message sent, exiting...
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
Thread 9: error: unknown host   --  Error is:  (0) "Success"
END OF PROGRAM
me@ubuntu:/home/me/socketProject#
```

The server received four test messages, as the above output suggests.

Sooooooooo…  there’s a lot of weirdness happening here.  There must be some bug with those “**THREAD X STARTED**” messages, because it looks like Threads 0, 1, and 6 never launched, while somehow Threads 3, 7, and 9 launched twice.  But `numThreads` == 10 and ten threads started, so I’ll ignore that issue for now.

Of greater concern is that six threads failed in their call to `gethostbyname()`.  I’ll admit: for this chunk of code, I copied an example from a textbook, and I can’t remember where I got it.  But I’m wondering if that `if(!host)` statement makes sense.  There was no problem when I beta tested this in the non-threaded version, but now…

Of even bigger weirdness is that the Errno code is "Success."  If its successful...  why is the call failing?  I feel like I'm missing something really, really obvious.

It also bothers me that this problem is inconsistent.  Sometimes when I test this, 7/10 threads successfully send.  Sometimes 1/10 do.  My average success rate is about 3/10.  If I’ve learned anything about C, its that inconsistent problems usually indicate that a variables has been successfully created but not initialized.  What might need to be initialized here?  The `host` struct?  I’m not sure.

I’ve been Googling this for about three hours now, but not pulling up anything useful.  Any suggestions or advice will be wildly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951925/gethostbyname-processes-resolving-consistently-even-from-different-threads.  This really seems like a thread safety issue.  Also check the man page for `gethostbyname`; it does not set errno on error, it sets h_errno.

Comment: @MarkA Hey Mark - HOLY COW, your comment is incredibly helpful!  I had no idea there were global memory issues with gethostbyname().  I had to spend a few hours refitting my code to use getaddrinfo(), but it was worth it.  Thank God you spotted this; an issue like this seems to be critical if you want to multithreading network programming.  Why isn't this information front and center in the tutorials?  Man, I'd be in a lot of pain if you hadn't chipped in.  Great catch, thanks so much.  I owe you a beer.

Comment: @Pete `gethostbyname()` is deprecated anyway, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank Remy.  I outfitted my code with getaddrinfo() and it runs much, much smoother now.  gethostbyname() must have been causing more havoc than I realized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, process, (void*) pack);
  pthread_detach(thread);

  free( pack->IP );
  free( pack );
```

... you create a resource specific for the new thread (`pack`) and then immediately delete it before the thread has completed its work!   These calls to free should be performed at the end of `process`

Comment: Wow, thanks Darren!  You were 100% right.  I never would have caught that.  I'm so used to pairing my calls to free() in the same function which calls malloc(), that I did it here without thinking.  Awesome, thanks for the assist!